# Function refactor this function to use "return" consistently in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have this function:

```
const colorTypesFunction = (e: any) => {

    const colorTypes = [
        {min: 0, color: "black"},
        {min: 0.01, color: "pink"}
    ]

    for (const {min, color} of colorTypes) {
        if (e.value > min) {
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

However sonarQube complains saying 'Refactor this function to use "return" consistently.'

So I have done this,

```
const colorTypesFunction = (e: any) => {
    
        const colorTypes = [
            {min: 0, color: "black"},
            {min: 0.01, color: "pink"}
        ]
    
        for (const {min, color} of colorTypes) {
            if (e.value > min) {
                return color;
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

Is this the correct way to address this issue?

Comment: whoa ... deja vu - did you ask this in the last 10 minutes?

Comment: "*Is this the correct way to address this issue?*" does Sonar complain any more? Also see https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-3801

Comment: @Jaromanda X, that question did not have the full code, so I updated with full code.